# Solve the differential equation $(1-y(x+y)\tan(xy))dx+(1-x(x+y)\tan(xy))dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to use the substitution $u=xy$,

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u-x^2}{x-x(x^2+u)\tan u}$$

but how can I move on from here? Any hints that could help me?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the substitutions 
$x + y = u$ and $xy = v$, then we have

$$dx + dy = du$$
$$xdy + ydx = dv$$

Then the equation becomes

$$du = u \tan vdv$$

$$\implies \frac{du}{u} = \tan v dv$$
$$\implies \ln u = - \ln \cos v + \text{constant}$$
$$\implies u \cos v = \text{constant} $$
$$\implies (x + y) \cos (xy) = \text{constant}$$

Comment: That's fascinating. What justifies $dx + dy = dy, xdy + ydx = dv$? I'm not familiar with these ways of computing differentials.

Comment: It should be $dx + dy = du$.  When I worked on the problem, I noticed the same expression $x + y$ and $xy$ repeating in the problem.  So I tried this substitutions.  Also from the book of differential equation I have read, it listed some special expressions which is useful like $d(xy) = xdy + ydx$ and $d(\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2}$.  This is useful in simplifying d.e. Expression.